# Evento mousedown

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo *JavaScript* y estoy teniendo problemas con los eventos. Solo quiero que en el momento de dar click me ejecute una simple función la cual genera una alerta.

```js
document.addEventListener("mousedown", maus);

function maus() {
  alert("alerta");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Prueba</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="maus.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu código funciona correctamente, ¿Cuál problema tienes?

Comment: Tu código  funciona. Le debes dar con el clic de en medio (la bolita con la que subes y bajas). Pero, siento que estas intentando que se ejecute el evento cuando das clic ¿No?

Comment: @EdgarGc Con cualquier botón funciona.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas,  no se por que no me funcionaba pero tenían razón no había nada mal en el código. ahora solo me gustaría que me explicaran si existe alguna forma de hacer que este código se ejecute solo al presionar el botón derecho quedo atento y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el Event "click"

```js
document.addEventListener("click", maus); 
   
  function maus()
  {
    alert("alerta");
  }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>            
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>Prueba</title>
  </head>                    
   <body>
         <script src="maus.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Edito:

El mouseDown también debería funcionarte. Tal vez prueba quitando los caracteres "~"